# Can't select the User Profile Application

Tags: user-profile-service

We are provisioning our User Profile Synchronization service.

In Central Admin, when we go to manage "Services on the Server" and click to "start" the User Profile Synchronization Service, it takes us to a dialogue where we configure the account it will use.

Problem is that there is no way to select the Profile Application!  When I click on the dropdown box, there are no entries to choose from!  Look at my dialogue box:

[image]

How can I get an entry there?

(Background info:  I am not able to start the two ForeFront services, and [I can't launch the FIM client](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/09/user-profile-synchronization-service-stuck-at-starting.html#ixzz2aX4V0Z4X), but at least my USer Profile Synchronization Service is "stopped" and not stuck at "starting".)

Since more screenshots were requested, here they are:

[image: UPS in Manage Service Applications]
[image: UPS Sync Service in Stopped Mode]

Comment: If you have setup user profile service application correctly, it should appear in dropdown. Try creating one more UPSA and try if its working

Comment: Should I delete the one I have?  I do notice that it seems not to have a proxy.

Comment: no  need to delete old one. just create new one see

Comment: I deleted it and recreated it.  Waqas figured out what the problem was (answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to start the FIM services manually. Do the steps in following way.

- create UPA service application.
- start UPA service from manage services on server
- now start UPA sync services from manage services on server

Make sure your farm administration account is in local  administration group on the server where you want to start the services.

**From your screen print, I am seeing that your user profile service is not properly created. i would delete user profile service application and create new one with new databases. At the end make sure it says started.**

Comment: FIM services are stopped. UPS is running in my server's services (else I would not be able to log in correctly via RDP). I have created the UPS Service in SCA (whence my screenshot).  My farm admin account is a local administrator.  So why isn't there anything to select in that dropdown?  I have the two ForeFront services to run using the farm account - is that wrong?

Comment: FIM services stoped because UPA Sync is not started, could you please share following screen shot....from central admin > application management> manage services applications....Highlight the User Profile Services...From Manage services on server....highlight the UPA and UPA Sync services(from all server in farm).

Comment: Waqas, I don't have a UPS Sync Service in "Manage Service Applications".  I don't see the need for the screenshot, but I will post it at your request.  And in "Manage Services on Server" My "User Profile Service" is in "start" mode, but the "User Profile Synchronization Service" is "stopped" and when I click on that, I get the problem that I posted in my question.

Comment: their should be no UPS sync service because it is component of User Profile Service Application. So what i asked, did you created User Profile Service Application(that's why i asked the screen shots of manage services application)...so please make sure the that you Created User Profile Services and it says started....otherwise you will not get FIM /Sync

Comment: I posted the screenshots.  I have the UPS Service created and running.

Comment: That is problem, if you see it is saying starting it should  be started, if I m not wrong.can you delet  it n recreate it?

Comment: Ah.  I get an error saying "the database you have chosen is not a valid synchronization database".  Then, when I refresh the page, I see the service application there as "starting".

Comment: so that is your problem, delete it and create a new UPA service application with new database.

Comment: I don't know how the one I have got to be "invalid".  Okay, so I entered a new database name for the UPS Service, and now I have a "started" User Profile Service.  AND I am able to start the User Profile Synchronization Service, too!

Comment: Can I safely delete the old Sync Database from SQL Server?

Comment: Ah, if you update your answer, I'll mark this solved.

Comment: awesome, so now you can delete the old created database as it is not being used....so be carefull and delete the old one not current one.

Comment: It's working!  It's working!  Now if I go to "Manage User Profile Service" I can see that I have 743 User Profiles!  Thank you, Waqas!

Comment: You welcome, i updated my answer, Hopefully you marked both question as answer...:)